# Select Single Element from Jagged Array

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm working on a problem that's making my brain melt although I don't think it should be this hard.  My example is long so I'll try to keep my question short!

I have an Array object that contains some elements that are also Arrays.  For example:

```
customerAddresses = new customer_address[]
{
  new    // address #1
  {
    customer_id = 6676979,
    customer_address_seq = 1,
    customer_address_match_codes = new []
    {
      new
      {
        customer_address_seq = 1,
        customer_id = 6676979,
        customer_match_code_id = 5
      }
    }
  },
  new    // address #2
  {
    customer_id = 6677070,
    customer_address_seq = 1,
    customer_address_match_codes = new []
    {
      new
      {
        customer_address_seq = 1,
        customer_id = 6677070,
        customer_match_code_id = 4
      },
      new
      {
        customer_address_seq = 1,
        customer_id = 6677070,
        customer_match_code_id = 5
      },
      new
      {
        customer_address_seq = 1,
        customer_id = 6677070,
        customer_match_code_id = 3
      }
    }
  },
  new    // address #3
  {
    customer_id = 6677070,
    customer_address_seq = 2,
    customer_address_match_code = new []
    {
      new
      {
        customer_address_seq = 2,
        customer_id = 6677070,
        customer_match_code_id = 4
      },
      new
      {
        customer_address_seq = 2,
        customer_id = 6677070,
        customer_match_code_id = 5
      }
    }
  }
};
```

As you can see, the Array contains a number of address records, with one record per combination of `customer_id` and `customer_address_seq`.  What I'm trying to do is find the best matching `customer_address` according to the following rules:

- There must be `customer_match_code_id` equal to 4 and there must be one equal to 5
- If there is a `customer_match_code_id` equal to 3, then consider that `customer_address` a stronger match.

According to the above rules, the 2nd `customer_address` element is the "best match".  However, the last bit of complexity in this problem is that there could be *multiple* "best matches".  How I need to handle that situation is by taking the `customer_address` record with the minimum `customer_id` and minimum `customer_address_seq`.

I was thinking that using LINQ would be my best bet, but I'm not experienced enough with it, so I just keep spinning my wheels.

Comment: I don't think you are going to do those and conditions with LINQ but I am not that strong with LINQ.  But I would use LINQ to orderby id, seq so once you find all 3 conditions you can stop.  And why do you repeat customerID in the matchCode?

Comment: Are you trying to match a customer addresse with a list of customer addresses and then returning a list of the customer address ID's that do match?  And from this list you want to return the best match to your original address?

Comment: Your `customer_address_match_code` lists currently don't get assigned to anything.

Comment: @RiskyMartin Yes, I am aware of that, thank you. I thought it would have been obvious that my example was not meant to represent real world code, but I suppose not. I've updated the example for any future reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to make a change to your class so that you are actually assigning your one collection to something:

```
customer_address_match_codes = new customer_address_match_code[]
{
  new
  {
    customer_address_seq = 1,
    customer_id = 6676979,
    customer_match_code_id = 5
  }
}
```

And then here is the LINQ that I've tested and does what you specify:

```
var result = (from c in customerAddresses
    let isMatch = c.customer_address_match_codes
                     .Where (cu => cu.customer_match_code_id == 4).Any () &&
                  c.customer_address_match_codes
                     .Where (cu => cu.customer_match_code_id == 5).Any ()
    let betterMatch = isMatch && c.customer_address_match_codes
                  .Where (cu => cu.customer_match_code_id == 3).Any () ? 1 : 0
    where isMatch == true
    orderby betterMatch descending, c.customer_id, c.customer_address_seq
    select c)
    .FirstOrDefault ();
```

I've worked up an example using your data with anonymous types here: http://ideone.com/wyteM

Comment: Thank you! In taking a glance over the answers, this seems to be the most accurate for my needs. Also thanks for "cleaning up" my example code a bit. TBH, since this class isn't mine, I wasn't sure how to write it as an example; obviously I got it wrong :-)

Comment: I'll test this out tomorrow on my code and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I created 7 different scenarios to test.  While all of the solutions produced correct results, this one fit my own style the best. Thanks again, and thanks for taking the time to create a working example!

Answer (score 0):

Not tested and not the same names but this should get you going

```
            customer cb = null;
            customer[] cs = new customer[] {new customer()};

            foreach (customer c in cs.OrderBy(x => x.id).ThenBy(y => y.seq))
            {
                if(c.addrs.Any(x => x.num == "5"))
                {
                    if(c.addrs.Any(x => x.num == "3"))
                    {
                        if (cb == null) cb = c;
                        if (c.addrs.Any(x => x.num == "2"))
                        {
                            cb = c;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for LINQ

```
var bestMatch = (from address in DATA
where address.customer_address_match_code.Any(
  x => x.customer_match_code_id == 4)
where address.customer_address_match_code.Any(
  x => x.customer_match_code_id == 5)
select address).OrderBy(
  x => x.customer_address_match_code.Where(
    y => y.customer_match_code_id >= 3)
  .OrderBy(y => y.customer_match_code_id)
  .First()
  .customer_match_code_id).FirstOrDefault();
```

My theory is this: Select addresses that have both a customer_match_code_id == 4 and a customer_match_code_id == 5. Then sort them by the the lowest customer_match_code_id they have that are at least 3, and then take the very first one. If there are a customer_match_code_id that equals 3 then that one is selected, if not, some else is selected. If nothing matches both 4 and 5 then null is returned.

Untested.

Answer (score 0):

Seems quite straight forward in LINQ:

```
var query =
    from ca in customerAddresses
    where ca.customer_address_match_codes.Any(
        mc => mc.customer_match_code_id == 4)
    where ca.customer_address_match_codes.Any(
        mc => mc.customer_match_code_id == 5)
    orderby ca.customer_id
    orderby ca.customer_address_seq
    orderby ca.customer_address_match_codes.Any(
        mc => mc.customer_match_code_id == 3) descending
    select ca;

var result = query.Take(1);
```

How does that look?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Using `Any()` as opposed to `Where().Any()` helped me slim down the code a bit.